# How to access Vue's methods from navigation guard?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I followed this guide: https://v2.cn.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods and added a method to the
Vue app in the `main.js`:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  data: {},
  methods: {aMethod: ()=> {}},
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

And then in my navigation guard, I tried to access app's methods by:

```
router.beforeEach(async function (to, from, next) {
  router.app.aMethod();
});
```

But get the error:

```
router.app.aMethod is not a function
```

So what is the possible way to **access the Vue app's methods**?

Some part of my `package.json`:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0"
  },
```

Comment: can you try store your new Vue() in a variable, const app = new Vue({...}), and then inside your callback use app.aMethod()?

Comment: one error that I see and they mention in the page you provided is that methods can't be defined as array functions since they won't bind against Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the `router`, finally found a workaround.

The `router` has a `apps` property, which turns out that the `router.apps[1]` contains the methods!

So the change is:

```
router.beforeEach(async function (to, from, next) {
-  router.app.aMethod();
+  router.apps[1].aMethod();
});
```